# C continuous integration

Tags: c, makefile, continuous-integration

I have a C project compiled with a set of makefiles. I would like to do continuous integration of this project. Do you know a tool such as Jenkins I can use for my C project?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I know I can use Jenkins with Java projects but I'm not aware about the possibility of using it with C projects...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins can do anything.

It's written in Java, but it's not restricted to Java projects at all. You can invoke tools like ant or maven, but you could also have a project that purely uses bash or other shell tools. This gives you the flexibility to do practically anything, as long as the tools  you want to use are installed.

For `C` projects, you're probably going to want to use `make`. Therefore, you can do this by invoking various shell operations, one after the other. The build will fail if any of the shell operations give a non-zero exit status.

You might like to take a look at the [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) to see whether there are any that could make this job even easier.

Comment: Continuous integration using `make` can be a challenge. Do you happen to have a resource  decreasing the steepness of the learning curve?